# How do i configure Dashboard report in jmeter?

Tags: automation, jmeter, dashboard

```
the report generating property m using are given below:
jmeter.reportgenerator.exclude_tc_from_top5_errors_by_sampler=true


jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.bytesThroughputOverTime.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.bytesThroughputOverTime.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Response Time Over Time graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimesOverTime.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimesOverTime.title=Response Time Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimesOverTime.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Percentiles Response Times over time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimePercentilesOverTime.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesOverTimeGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimePercentilesOverTime.title Response Time Percentiles Over Time (successful requests only)
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimePercentilesOverTime.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Synthetic Response Time Distribution
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.syntheticResponseTimeDistribution.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.SyntheticResponseTimeDistributionGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.syntheticResponseTimeDistribution.title=Synthetic Response Times Distribution
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.syntheticResponseTimeDistribution.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.syntheticResponseTimeDistribution.property.set_satisfied_threshold=${jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold}
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.syntheticResponseTimeDistribution.property.set_tolerated_threshold=${jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold}

# Latencies Over Time graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyOverTimeGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.title=Latencies Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Connect Time Over Time graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.connectTimeOverTime.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ConnectTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.connectTimeOverTime.title=Connect Time Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.connectTimeOverTime.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Response Time Vs Request graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeVsRequest.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeVSRequestGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeVsRequest.title=Response Time Vs Request
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeVsRequest.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeVsRequest.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Latencies Vs Request graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyVSRequestGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.title=Latencies Vs Request
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Hits Per Second graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.hitsPerSecond.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.HitsPerSecondGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.hitsPerSecond.title=Hits Per Second
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.hitsPerSecond.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.hitsPerSecond.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Codes Per Second graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.codesPerSecond.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CodesPerSecondGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.codesPerSecond.title=Codes Per Second
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.codesPerSecond.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.codesPerSecond.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Transactions Per Second graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.transactionsPerSecond.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TransactionsPerSecondGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.transactionsPerSecond.title=Transactions Per Second
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.transactionsPerSecond.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}
```

I can generate dashboard report successfully but i want to change few things 
        in  report like:
        1-Dashboard look.
        2-Deleting and adding things etc.[enter image description here][1]
i already try many method to figure this out but it doesn't work for me, suggest me some answers to solve this, as i am the beginner in the j meter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

-g then path of your jmx file -o and path of your result dashboard

run this on cmd and do some configuration in your reportgenerate.property file